# Status register description in document

Tags: assembly, avr, atmel

Reading AVR assembler instruction set documentation.

[image]

What those red highlighted registers means? In some cases they are inverted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`R` in this case means the result. The formulas give how the flags correspond to the bits of the result. For example `N=R7` means bit #7 of the result is copied into the negative flag. Which is what the verbal description says too. You should also know that in those boolean formulas `•` means `AND`, `+` means `OR`, `⨁` means `XOR`.

For your information, the notations used are listed on the first two pages of the manual (at least in the one I have), among others it lists:

```
Registers and Operands
Rd:    Destination (and source) register in the Register File
Rr:    Source register in the Register File
R:     Result after instruction is executed
```